# Perform a second merge when the result of the first merge was empty

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

My apologies in advance for the formatting.

Let's say I have two data frames, one with names and phone numbers, and the other with an ID#, and two name-phone pairs.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['John Doe', '555-555-5555'], ['Jane Doe', '555-555-5556'], ['Joe Doe', '555-555-5557']], columns=['Name', 'Phone'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['111','Jimmy Doe', '555-555-5552', 'John Doe', '555-555-5555'], ['112', 'Jane Doe', '555-555-5556', 'Joan Doe','555-555-5553'], ['113','Joe Doe', '555-555-5554', 'Joe Doe', '555-555-5557']], columns=['ID','Name1', 'Phone1', 'Name2', 'Phone2'])
```

I want to merge the two data frames so I get the ID number from df2 that corresponds with the person data on df1. In my current set up, I am simply merging the data frames multiple times, first on the Name1-Phone1 set, and next on the Name2-Phone2 set.

Performing this, I'd get a blank value in the first and third row of the first ID column (Probably ID_X) and a value in the second.

What I'm trying to do is write a function where, if the outcome of the first merge is blank, then merge again using the second name set. The main conceptual stumbling block I'm having is how to apply a merge, which is my understanding I have to do based on the entire data frame, on just the rows where the ID column was blank.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of performing multiple merges, you can reshape the second DataFrame using `pd.wide_to_long` so that you can perform a single merge. With grouped columns ['NameX', 'PhoneX'] wide to long is a really user friendly option to reshape.

```
df2 = (pd.wide_to_long(df2, i='ID', j='to_drop', stubnames=['Name', 'Phone'])
         .reset_index()
         .drop(columns='to_drop'))
#    ID       Name         Phone
#0  111  Jimmy Doe  555-555-5552
#1  112   Jane Doe  555-555-5556
#2  113    Joe Doe  555-555-5554
#3  111   John Doe  555-555-5555
#4  112   Joan Doe  555-555-5553
#5  113    Joe Doe  555-555-5557

df1.merge(df2, how='left')
```

---

```
       Name         Phone   ID
0  John Doe  555-555-5555  111
1  Jane Doe  555-555-5556  112
2   Joe Doe  555-555-5557  113
```

Comment: I will definitely be trying this when I'm in the office tomorrow (my data is a bit more complicated than the example, so I want to check that) but this already looks promising. Up voted for now, and if it works I'll mark it as the answer. Thank you!

Comment: If it doesn’t work or merges too many things in the cases of matches in multiple groups,  I can provide an iterative approach, just @ me to grab my attention and I can update

Comment: I appreciate all your help.